# iOS: Runtime error when testing custom Framework with 3rd-party CocoaPod dependency (ARCore)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, arcore, ios-frameworks

Our (mostly Android-backgrounded:)) team is developing partner iOS Swift Framework (SDK) with some 3rd-party dependencies inside.

Framework itself has several 3rd-party dependencies all embedded with CocoaPods (*Edit: we also tried SPM, but ATM rejected it for a project*), and they're working like a charm either during compile time or while testing on device/simulator, while being embedded inside a simple test "partner" app. No general problems here.

But there is one essential 3rd-party lib: [ARCore](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-ios-sdk/issues/52) Augmented Faces, embedding which causes a problem.

So we're currently stuck with using common workspace and 2 projects (test app and framework itself) within it, also with CocoaPods base structure on top workspace level:  [image: base structure]

[image: workspace struct]

The Podfile here currently looks like this, inspired by the structure mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42480097/6405022:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

workspace 'Untitled.xcworkspace'

abstract_target 'CommonPods' do
    # ... some other common 3rd-party dependencies here ...
    pod 'ARCore/AugmentedFaces', '~> 1.30.0'

    target 'TestApp' do
        project 'TestApp/TestApp.xcodeproj'
    end

    target 'Framework' do
        project 'Framework/Framework.xcodeproj'
    end

end
```

With that said, partner test app *builds* just fine.

The problem which we're facing happens right after partner app launch and is always supported by crash:

> ...
> Lots of similar duplication warnings like below comes here
> ...
>
> objc[58698]: Class GARPseudonymousID is implemented in both
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21A274AC-31B1-4AE6-9E3F-1BF720C9B221/TestApp.app/Frameworks/Framework.framework/Framework
> (0x103d9e0d8) and
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21A274AC-31B1-4AE6-9E3F-1BF720C9B221/TestApp.app/TestApp
> (0x10131e440). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> objc[58698]: Class GARPseudonymousIDStore is implemented in both
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21A274AC-31B1-4AE6-9E3F-1BF720C9B221/TestApp.app/Frameworks/Framework.framework/Framework
> (0x103d9e128) and
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21A274AC-31B1-4AE6-9E3F-1BF720C9B221/TestApp.app/TestApp
> (0x10131e490). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> F0621 20:33:23.600151       1 registration.h:175] Function with name
> CallbackPacketCalculator already registered.
>
> *** Check failure stack trace: *** dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib
> dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib

---

What we already know:

- Project runs fine on a simulator (as far as we tried), but ***crashes on real device***
- It happens in runtime and only when adding ARCore via CocoaPods and setting pod 'ARCore/AugmentedFaces' both for TestApp and Framework targets.
- It doesn't make any difference if we're trying to reference Framework API in partner app code (via `import Framework` and/or calling its API methods) or not, but:
- When setting pod 'ARCore/AugmentedFaces' for **TestApp only**, it cannot be accessed inside Framework Swift code in compile time.
- When setting pod 'ARCore/AugmentedFaces' for **Framework only**, we get `No Such Module: ARCore` error via Swift linter right on `import Framework` line (essentially the place where partner app has an entry to our framework, f.e. in AppDelegate or else).
- `Class N is implemented in both...` warning references to all dependencies, but as far as we go only ARCore usage causes crashes and error in log afterwards.
- ARCore (obviously) works perfectly fine when being added as pod to any simple iOS app project w/o custom modules including it.
- Removing ARCore pod and references to it completely let us manually test the rest of Framework functionality w/o problems.

We're not still 100% sure if class/method duplication issues cause the crash problem, but we're mostly sure it happens when trying to have an ARCore pod inside the both Framework target and app target (or in abstract target on top level). Anyways, getting rid of the pod in any separate Target causes problems mentioned in upper thesises (with current approach).

Any thoughts or workaround (maybe only except deriving 3rd party source code:)) will be much appreciated!

---

**Edit:** now, after making an attempt to add some other 3rd-party packages via CocoaPods and having a successful launch with them embedded excluding ARCore, we realize that crashes should be strictly related to ARCore pod usage.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some headache and playing with pods/configurations, I somehow managed to successfully launch the whole project with following structure, but only(!) with Release configuration:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

workspace 'Common.xcworkspace'

abstract_target 'CommonPods' do
    # ... some other common 3rd-party dependencies here ...

    target 'TestApp' do
        project 'TestApp/TestApp.xcodeproj'
    end

    target 'Framework' do
        pod 'ARCore/AugmentedFaces', '~> 1.30.0'
        project 'Framework/Framework.xcodeproj'
    end

end
```

[image]

Seems like a bit poor workaround, but at least custom framework has the access to all desired 3rd-party dependencies and remains fully testable as for now.